# Cython: Wrapping a C++ class that takes different instances of itself as inputs

Tags: python, c++, cython

I recently started working on a fast python library full of calculus operations, it would help me learn the maths behind AI much better. I think the problem with tensorflow is that everything just happens, I would learn a lot from making it happen :)

The main class in this library is the Variable class, which has 3 ways to init it- as a constant, independent variable or a function. I want to wrap this class in cython. So far, the class just has a constructor and a getValue function which would return a function that gives the class value.

The problem is that when you initialize it as a function, the constructor needs two other instances of the Variable class and the operation between them (the idea is that later, I would combine these function variables to make any function). I want to wrap this in cython:
variable.pyx:

```
cdef extern from "Variable.h" namespace "calc":
cdef cppclass Variable:
    float value;
    Variable();
    Variable(float value);
    Variable(Variable a, Variable b, char op);
    float getValue();

cdef class _Variable:
    cdef Variable thisptr 
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = Variable()
    def __cinit__(self, float x):
        self.thisptr = Variable(x)
    def __cinit__(self, Variable a, Variable b, char g):
        self.thisptr = Variable(a,b,g)
    def getValue(self):
        self.thisptr.getValue()
```

Variable.h:

```
namespace calc {
class Variable {
    public:
        float value;
        Variable();
        Variable(float value);
        Variable(Variable a, Variable b, char op);
        ~Variable();
        float getValue();
};
}
```

and setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(ext_modules=[Extension("pyCalc", ["variable.pyx", "Variable.cpp"], language="c++",)],
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext})
```

Surprisingly, overloading seems to be working fine, the problem arises  here **def __cinit__(self, Variable a, Variable b, char g):** because Variable doesnt exist in python, only _Variable does. I can't pass _Variable because it doesn't exist in C++.

What do you think I should do? How can I pass another instance of the C++ class in Python where it's technically a different class, just using the C++ code?

Thank You very much! I honestly have no idea what to do next :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the standard way of doing it would be:

```
def __cinit__(self, _Variable a, _Variable b, char g):
    self.thisptr = Variable(a.thisptr,b.thisptr,g)
```

I have no cython installation at hand right now and not proficient enough, to be sure that there aren't other problems. So try it out!

On a slightly different note:  Maybe the way you declared the constructor is intentional, but normally one would like to avoid the coping of `a` and `b` and use calling by reference: `Variable(const Variable &a, const Variable &b, char op);` instead of calling by value, as you did.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) You are still wrong, but the way you wrote it suddenly made me understand how it works - that _Variable is the python version and _Variable.thisptr is the c++ version of it. Thanks to you I did `Variable(a.thisptr,b.thisptr,g)` and that made me realise that the main call (as well as a and b) should be the python _Variable for this to work. Thank you very much :)

Comment: The correct call is: `def __cinit__(self, _Variable a, _Variable b, char g):
        self.thisptr = Variable(a.thisptr,b.thisptr,g)`

Comment: Thanks for the tips, so far I've only coded to do something, not really focusing on best practices, I will have to work on that. Also, it turns out overloading the cinit function won't work so I will need to change it a bit.

Comment: @user3000140 you are right, i forgot the underscores! Actually i was not sure about overloading, i think one could overload cdefs but not defs.